# Not able to position Jquery dialog windows dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have following code

```js
$(function(){
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto"
   });

    $('button').each(function(i) {
        var el = $(this);
       el.click(function () {
            $('.dialog').eq(i).dialog('open');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<button id="opener_1">Enlarge</button>
<div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge 1
  <img class="large_1" src="./large1.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

 <button id="opener_2">Enlarge</button>
 <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge 2
  <img class="large_2" src="./large2.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

 <button id="opener_3">Enlarge</button>
 <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge 3
  <img class="large_3" src="./large3.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

Right now each dialog windows are showing top on every one. I am trying to make it separate its position but I failed. I tried with "position" but not able to achieve the result.

Comment: What is the result that you want?

Comment: I am trying to position the dialog box just below the each one so that every one can see the window